# How do I make subtitles / captions in Final Cut Pro?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I got Final Cut Pro to make translated subtitles for a short 18-minute video, but am having a lot of trouble with it. I create a bunch of Titles but seems like I have to reposition that title to the bottom of the video manually for each Title and it's very cumbersome. Am I doing it right?

Thanks

Comment: It will always be cumbersome in FCP unless you buy some other software designed for this. But at least you can keep duplicating one title and editing the text so they are always positioned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to do this - the way you are doing it, and the other is by using a text track in QuickTime.

The advantages of the way you are doing it:

- You get more exact control over the font
- You can ensure they show up
- It works 100% of the time.

The advantages of doing it the other way (with a text track in QuickTime):

- The captions are optional, and can be turned on or off by the viewer.
- A single video file can be captioned in different languages, and those captions can be selected by the user.

Comment: After going true the English, does on think this answer deserves a up vote?